# PHP-FPM seems busy

Tags: nginx, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I am receiving the following error in `php-fpm` error logs

> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:31] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 131 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:32] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 161 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:33] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 18 idle, and 191 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:46] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 210 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:47] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 11 idle, and 218 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:48] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 24 idle, and 234 total children
>
> [13-Jun-2017 23:49:49] WARNING: [pool instahd.info] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 27 idle, and 240 total children

My current PHP-FPM pool setting is following

```
pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 35
pm.min_spare_servers = 30
pm.max_spare_servers = 70
pm.max_children = 2500
pm.max_requests = 2500
```

I have 64GB RAM

Comment: You need to find out the average memory consumption of your PHP worker processes, and then find out reasonable number or workers you need to operate your site by checking your logs when PHP needs to spawn new workers. If the number of workers multiplied by their memory usage exceeds your available RAM, then you need to install more RAM.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen My average memory consumption is less then 15MB. I'm not experienced person for tuning PHP-FPM. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: You simply increase the number of of `start_servers` so that there are enough for your regular traffic (the number of concurrent visitors). And then you keep in mind that the memory usage does not exceed available RAM when maximum number of workers is activee.